# Bokeh HoverTool custom font and newlines from Python

Tags: javascript, python, plot, bokeh

My tooltips on my plot are much too large and overflow the plot, as the strings they display are long. I have been browsing around the source (and a bit of the javascript), but haven't found anywhere that might let me set the font **without** spinning my own HTML or JavaScript (i.e. via some Python object). I've also tried naively adding `<br>` and `\n` characters into the tooltip string, but that didn't work.

How can I change my tooltip fonts (or possibly other relevant attributes) easily?

**Update**: I've tried setting the font small, but am still unable to get newlines in the tooltip. Here is my tooltip code:

`hover.tooltips = """
        y: $y <br>
        date: @dates <br>
        items: <br><font face="Arial" size="1">@items</font>
        """`

The issue is, each item from the `items` source is a variable length list, and I wish to separate each entry in the list by a newline rendered in the tooltip

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing lots of digging around, it seemed impossible with the current version of Bokeh without doing some source editing.

I was able to achieve the effect newlines by changing the way `bokeh.js` parses the strings

in my ColumnDataSource with the keyword argument `items = [['point0item0<br>', 'point0item1<br>'],['point1item1<br>', ...], ...]`

I changed the parsing of collection tooltips (doesn't work for raw string tooltips)
in `bokeh.js` so that it would respect `<br>` items in the strings it renders by changing the code from

```
value = Util.replace_placeholders(value, ds, i, vars);
td.append($('<span>').html(value));
```

to

```
value = Util.replace_placeholders(value, ds, i, vars);
value = value.replace(/,/g, "");
value = value.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
value = value.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
td.append($('<span>').html(value));
```

I haven't tested this beyond my example, and I hardly ever write javascript, so user beware. I also noticed that the `.html(value)` call changed from `.text(value)` between Bokeh version (0.9.2) and (0.9.3), so that any HTML code in the value string would be respected, but the `<br>` were already encoded (in my mind, 'broken' ;) by `Util.replace_placeholders()`

In Python, the tooltip setting looks like this:

```
hover.tooltips=[
        ("grade", "$y"),
        ("date", "@dates"),
        ("items", "@items"),
    ]
```

A screenshot of hovering over the same data point now looks like this

[image: four strings separated by HTML newlines]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [custom tooltip](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip), which should let you do what you need.

At the moment, you've probably got something like:

```
hover.tooltips = [
    ("index", "$index"),
    ("foo", "@foo"),
    ("bar", "@bar"),
]
```

Try:

```
hover.tooltips = """
    The index of my data is: $index <br>
    My foo property is bold <strong>@foo</strong>
    I could use a custom font <font face="Arial" size="3">@bar </font>
"""
```

You can see examples in the docs link above and in a couple of examples that are in the bokeh repo:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/interactions/us_marriages_divorces/us_marriages_divorces_interactive.py#L64

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/glyphs/sprint.py#L90

Comment: Thanks, +1, I saw these examples, however I was hoping to avoid writing my own HTML (I realized I said JS in the question -- my fault). Is there no Python object where some default font attributes are saved and that I could modify?

Comment: No, I'm afraid that you will need to write your own HTML.

Comment: If `bar` is a list of several items, is there a way I can set the tooltip to have newlines for each item?

Answer (score 2):

I know this issue is old but neither answer helped me solve the problem, which is to somehow add newlines into a single variable's rendered tooltip string.

### TL;DR

Use `{safe}` to prevent HTML escapes and manually change the tooltip strings to add HTML `<br>` linebreaks.

---

@birdsarah's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32407915/7253166) helped to added newlines between the tooltip strings of different variables. @eqzx's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32616279/7253166) involved editing bokeh source code, which wasn't an option for me. Neither answer enabled line breaks for data that were in lists.

Googling around, I came across [this discourse thread](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/hover-tool-plotting-display-wrapped-lines-of-text-if-tooltip-on-left-hand-side-of-cursor/2734/2) that pointed to the `{safe}` modifier, which is [documented](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip) but I hadn't noticed it.

You basically have to do two things:

1. Manually add HTML linebreaks in the `items` column to separate each item in the list.
2. Add the `{safe}` modifier to the item's tooltip so that HTML characters are not escaped.

Lets suppose your data is in a `pd.DataFrame`, and that the `items` column holds lists for each cell in the data frame.

```py
data.items = data.items.transform(lambda x: "<br>".join(x))

...

hover.tooltips = """
        y: $y <br>
        date: @dates <br>
        items: <br><font face="Arial" size="1">@items{safe}</font>
        """
```

This will split each item in the `@items` column and render them in separate lines in the tooltip string.